# Cross-Referring between properties in Notion Timeline

Tags: project-management, notion

I have created a Notion timeline database.

It has, say, Project A which has a "Start Date" property and "End Date Property" (I know these can be clubbed in the same property "Date" by toggling an option, but for some reason, I have to keep it like this).

Now, when I add another project - Project B, I want Notion to automatically use the "Start Date" property as the "End Date" property of previous project A.

Is there a way to do that? Can I use some formula to use a property's previous value (End date of Project A) in a project as value for a different property in a different project (Start Date in Project B)?